# EGMO $2013$ Problem $5$ doubt in the solution

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Let $\Omega$ be the circumcircle of the triangle $ABC$. The circle $\omega$ is tangent to the sides $AC$ and $BC$, and it is internally tangent to the circle $\Omega$ at the point $P$. A line parallel to $AB$ intersecting the interior of triangle $ABC$ is tangent to $\omega$ at $Q$.
> Prove that $\angle ACP = \angle QCB$.

In this solution https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c618937h1648567_problem_831_egmo_20135 (last one)

I have a few things that i did not understand ...

**$1$)** Why $\sqrt{ab}$ inversion around $C$ followed by a reflection over the $C$-angle bisector sends $\omega$ to the $C$-excircle ?

**$2$)** And why it sends $P$ to $X$ and why it solves problem ?

thankyou very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A'$ denote the inverse of $A$ after that inversion you mentioned.Then,line $BC$ will go to the circumcircle of $ABC$ of the circumcircle.(Since $BC$ does not pass through $A$)
.$AB$ and $AC$ line remains there.SO,the inverse of $\omega$ will be tangent to line $AB,AC,BC$,which is simple the excircle.and tangency points would be inverse of one another implying $P$ goes to $X$

Comment: thanks,but why  inverse of ω will be tangent to line $BC$ ?

Comment: Cause it was tangent to arc BC which maps to segment BC

Comment: ohh,yes thankyou very much